# Transform object in js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want transform a Javascript object to a different form. Lets take an example.

may be I have an object like this,

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "abc",
    "sub": [
      "bbb",
      "ccc"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 8,
    "name": "abc1",
    "sub": [
      "bbb1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 11,
    "name": "abc"
  }
]
```

and I want to transform that like below,

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "abc",
    "sub": [
      {
        "sub": "bbb"
      },
      {
        "sub": "ccc"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 8,
    "name": "abc1",
    "sub": [
      {
        "sub": "bbb1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 11,
    "name": "abc"
  }
]
```

my code looks something like this,

```
x.map(({ sub }) => ({ sub: sub }));
```

If i try this, I'm getting a result something like this,

```
[{"sub":["bbb","ccc"]},{"sub":["bbb1"]},{}]
```

can anyone please help me to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried so far

Comment: added along with the question body.

Comment: `.map(el => ({...el, sub: el.sub?.map(sub => ({ sub })) || undefined })))`. If you prefer to have an empty array instead of `undefined` when the original element has no `sub`, replace `undefined` with `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) twice along with the spread operator

```js
let a = [
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "abc",
    "sub": [
      "bbb",
      "ccc"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 8,
    "name": "abc1",
    "sub": [
      "bbb1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 11,
    "name": "abc"
  }
]

let b = a.map((el) => {
  if(el.sub){
        let c = el.sub.map(el2 => {
        return {sub: el2}
      })
      el = {...el,sub: c}
   }
   return el;
})

console.log(b)
```

Comment: Oh hell yeah, it worked. Thanks a ton,